# Node.js Express app.get() doesn't work in cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron

I want to make a 10-minutes cron, which is executing some actions, but at first, I've got a problem with how to simply call an action. I'm using MEAN.js framework. My approach is following:

---

**server.js, at the bottom**

```
new CronJob('* */10 * * * *', function() {
    console.log("CronJob executed");
    app.get('/cronBarbarianAttack', function(req, res) {
    });
}, null, true);
```

**cron.server.routes.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
    var cron = require('../../app/controllers/cron.server.controller');

    // Cron Routes
    app.route('/cronBarbarianAttack').get(cron.barbarianAttack);

};
```

**cron.server.controller.js**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
    Game = mongoose.model('Game'),
    _ = require('lodash');

exports.barbarianAttack = function(req, res) { 
    console.log("executed");
    res.json(null);
};
```

But this doesn't call the controller function. It only prints to console "CronJob Executed", without second "executed" message. Where is the problem and what's wrong with my approach? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.get

**app.get()** only routes your HTTP GET requests to specified callback.

There is no HTTP request, so nothing was called.

You do not need express framework to pass callback to cronjob.

Assume you use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron), so check the docs to this project to proper write cron jobs